# Finding Specific Rows in Table Using ROW() Causing Query to Execute Slowly in mySQL

Tags: mysql, performance, match, row, execution

I am trying to run a query to find matching values in two separate tables, but I am not happy with my execution time. I was wondering if there was some different syntax that I could use instead of ROW() that would provide better performance.

Current Query:

```
SELECT de.rowID, de.EffRate, li.SessionID FROM tblClockDetail li
  INNER JOIN tblCardDetail de
    ON de.TimeIn = li.LogInTime AND 
       de.TimeOut = li.LogOutTime AND 
       de.Employee = li.Employee
WHERE ROW(de.Employee, li.SessionID) IN (SELECT * FROM tblSessionDetails)
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What version of MySQL?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out all I needed were some additional WHERE checks:

```
WHERE ROW(de.Employee, li.SessionID) IN (SELECT * FROM tblSessionDetails) 
AND li.SessionID IS NOT NULL AND
li.SessionID != 0
```

This drastically reduced my execution time.

Answer (score 0):

"Row constructors", historically, have been poorly optimized.

See if a simple JOIN works better:

```
SELECT de.rowID, de.EffRate, li.SessionID
    FROM tblClockDetail AS li
    JOIN tblCardDetail AS de
      ON  de.TimeIn = li.LogInTime
      AND de.TimeOut = li.LogOutTime
      AND de.Employee = li.Employee
    JOIN tblSessionDetails AS td
      ON de.Employee = td.Employee
     AND li.SessionID = td.SessionID;
```

with these composite indexes:

```
de:  INDEX(TimeIn, TimeOut, Employee)
li:  INDEX(LogInTime, LogOutTime, Employee, SessionID)
td:  INDEX(Employee, SessionID)
```

For further discussion, please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` and how big the tables are.